# Conditional Aliasing with Multiple Lookups

Tags: mysql, sql

Say that you have a table with two (or more) columns which link to another table:

```
 house_history         houses
---------------       --------
OwnerID               HouseID
PreviousHouseID       Address
CurrentHouseID
```

and you wanted to return data from each of those IDs:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------
|OwnerID|        PreviousAddress    |      CurrentAddress     |
---------------------------------------------------------------
         (linked to PreviousHouseID) (linked to CurrentHouseID)
```

How would you go about doing that? (specifically I'm interested in using MySQL)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT OwnerId, p.Address as PreviousAddress, c.Address as CurrentAddress
FROM house_history h
LEFT JOIN houses p ON h.PreviousHouseID = p.HouseID
LEFT JOIN houses c ON h.CurrentHouseID = c.HouseID
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed :) And I gotta give it to Nathaniel because he "hit the buzzer" just a minute or two first. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
SELECT hh.OwnerID,h1.Address,h2.Address
FROM house_history hh 
LEFT JOIN house h1 ON h1.HouseId = hh.PreviousHouseID
LEFT JOIN house h2 ON h2.HouseId = hh.CurrentHouseID
```

Probably you may required **LEFT JOIN** insted of **INNER JOIN** because it works also when current and previous house is null

Comment: Moyed; minor issue, but your second alias is h1, but I think you mean h2. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    house_history.OwnerID
    , houses_previous.Address AS PreviousAddress
    , houses_current.houses.Address AS CurrentAddress
FROM house_history
    LEFT JOIN houses AS houses_current ON (house_history.CurrentHouseID = houses_current.HouseID)
    LEFT JOIN houses AS houses_previous ON (house_history.PreviousHouseID = houses_previous.HouseID);
```